# Flutter: Passing data from two stateful widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

May I know what to do if let's say I have StatefulWidget_1 with an object Object_1 that I will pass to StatefulWidget_2, do some changes to Object_1 then pass it back to StatefulWidget_1. Is this setup possible? May I know the suggested solution?

I am having trouble since modifications done by StatefulWidget_2 are discarded when accessing Object_1 in StatefulWidget_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by passing a function in StatefulWidget_2 from StatefulWidget_1 that does the modification on Object_1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your object1 is part of the state of statefulwedget1.

now ,the problem becomes, how to make your statefulwidget2 to change object1 ?

common wisdom for state management for flutter suggest BloC pattern

using streams and streambuilders ,this will help very much in doing that.

Comment: May I know what do you mean by "part" of the state? Basically object 1 is just an object created in the first stateful widget.

Comment: part of the state means its defined inside the state class belongs to the statefulwedget because there may be other objects too defined there .. so every object defined in the state class is "part" of the state

Comment: So, if that's the case, I need to use streams? or that BloC pattern? Hmm.

Comment: for this simple case you will need a combination of stream and  StreamBuilder for more complex states you should use BloC as I mentioned State management in flutter is debatable about what to use that is why said "common wisdom" hope that help you